# How to store the close of a bar for future reference

Tags: algorithm, pine-script

I was trying to code my strategy in pine script on tradingview and I am stuck in coding the exit condition. My exit condition for a long position is as follows - If the current bar closes below the low of the bar in which the trade was initiated then exit else keep it live.

Would be of great help if anyone could resolve this.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of a series when a particular condition is met using the function `valuewhen`, in your case:

```
exit_lvl = valuewhen(long_condition,low,0)
```

then you can use:

```
strategy.close("Long Entry Id",cross(close,exit_lvl))
```

where `Long Entry Id` is your long order identifier.